# How do I make a document wait for an assigned input value?

Tags: javascript, html, input, textbox

I am writing a number guessing game. Every time I run the document it automatically goes to my outer else statement and I know why, but I can't figure out how to make it wait for an input value of the textbox. I want to set "guess" = to the value of the text box by pressing submit which will then enter the if statements. At the moment it is automatically setting to null and causing the error. Here is the code.

```
<head>
        <title>Guessing Game</title>
</head>

<body>
        <h1>Number Guessing Game</h1><br>
        <button onclick = "search(1,100)">Press to play!</button>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var counter = 0;
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*100+1);
    function search(first, last){
                document.open();
                document.write("<h1>Number Guessing Game</h1><br>");
                document.write("<input id = 'guessBox' type = 'text'>&nbsp;");
                document.write("<input type = 'submit' id = 'submit' value = 'Submit'><br>");
                document.write("<h2>Numbers Left</h2>");
                for(var i = first; i <= last; i++){
                    document.write(i + " ");
                }
                document.write("<br><br><h3>Number of tries: " + counter + "</h3>");
                document.close();
                var guess = document.getElementById('guessBox').value;
                //var guess = prompt("Guess!");
                myguess = parseInt(guess);
        if(myguess <= last && myguess >= first && cont == true){
            if(myguess == randomNumber){
                counter++;
                if(counter <=3){
                alert("WOW, that was amazingly quick! You found it in " + counter + " tries.");
                }
                else if(counter < 6 && counter >= 4){
                    alert("Not bad! You found it in " + counter + " tries.");
                }
                else if(counter < 10 && counter >= 6){
                    alert("Ouch! You found it in " + counter + " tries.");
                }
                else{
                    alert("Having a bad day aren't you? You found it in "+ counter + " tries");
                }

            }
            else if(myguess < randomNumber){
                first = myguess+1;
                alert("Try again! The number is higher.");
                counter++;
                search(first, last);
            }
            else{
                last = myguess-1;
                alert("Try again! The number is lower.");
                counter++;
                search(first, last);        
            }
        }
        else{
            alert("Invalid Number, try again.");
            search(first, last);
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Using document.write on the same document is a bad idea.

Comment: never use document.write

Comment: Appreciate the advice, but that didn't really answer the question.

Comment: At this line, `if(myguess <= last && myguess >= first && cont == true){`, you check the variable `cont`, which I can't find in your code, so if it is not declared and set somewhere, you code will always take the outer route

Comment: Second, you need to split your `search` function into 2 functions, one that generates the input, one that runs when someone entered a value (which can be fired on keypress or with a button)

Comment: I ended up determining that I needed two functions. One that generates the game board and one that inputs 3 parameters, first, last, and guess. You have confirmed that for me!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to disable the button, then add an onChange event to your text box so that you can enable the button once you have the desired input?  You will need to add an ID or Name value to your button so it can be accessed?  And to add what @LGSon added:

if(myguess <= last && myguess >= first && cont == true){, you check the variable cont, which I can't find in your code, so if it is not declared and set somewhere, you code will always take the outer route.

Second, you need to split your search function into 2 functions, one that generates the input, one that runs when someone entered a value (which can be fired on keypress or with a button)

Comment: The whole search method automatically calls, even before having the opportunity to input text.

Comment: wrap your javascript in a function, then call the function from the button on click event.

Comment: You were half way though, update your answer with the sum of my comments and you'll get my upvote

Comment: @LGSon on this question?

Comment: Yes, why not. My above comments were confirmed by the OP in his a last comment, and as you more or less pointed out the same, you could make a minor update to cover that

Comment: Thanks @LGSon you have helped a lot

Comment: I've got it everyone. Thanks for the advice!